# What causes this constructor to delegate to itself when it takes an initializer list and delegates a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

struct test
{
    using t = std::vector<test>;
    test(t const &v)
    {
    }
    test(t &&v)
    {
    }
    test(std::initializer_list<test> v)
    : test{t{v}} //error
    {
    }
};
```

Both [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f6c9ea6421cc0c0) and [GCC](http://ideone.com/c06v0O) complain that the third constructor, the one taking the initializer list, delegates to itself. I don't understand how this is possible though, because you can't construct an initializer list from a vector.

It is trivial to fix the error by replacing the outer curly braces with round parenthesis, but why would this be an issue in the first place? This almost identical program compiles just fine:

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>

struct a {};
struct b {};

struct test
{
    test(a const &)
    {
    }
    test(a &&)
    {
    }
    test(std::initializer_list<b> v)
    : test{a{}} //no error, still using curly braces
    {
    }
};
```

Interestingly, with the above second example, the error reappears if you substitute `b` with `test`. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: FWIW, the posted code works without any problem on my desktop using g++ 4.8.2 but fails at http://ideone.com/ejyM5e.

Comment: @Nawaz the alias does not get instantiated until it is used: http://ideone.com/fwE5ds this is out of the scope of this question, I suggest you research it yourself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `t{v}` is `std::vector<test>`. The idea is that init-list constructors are always preferred wrt any other constructors, so `test{t{v}}` will first try to call an init-list constructor, if one exists, and if the types are compatible. In your case, this is possible, since `test` itself can be implicitly constructed from a `std::vector<test>` (via your first 2 constructors), so the compiler ends up delegating to the init-list constructor, hence the error.

In the second case, there is no ambiguity, since the type `a{}`is not implicitly convertible anymore to `std::initializer_list<b>`.

Make the constructors `explicit` in the first example, or call the base constructor with `test(t{v})` instead, and your ambiguity will disappear (the compiler won't perform the implicit conversion anymore).

A simpler example (live [here](http://ideone.com/dy3ygx)) that exhibits essentially the same behaviour as your first example is:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct test
{
    /*explicit*/ test(int){} // uncomment explicit and no more errors
    test( std::initializer_list<test> v)
        : test{42} {} // error, implicitly converts 42 to test(42) via the test(int)
};

int main(){}
```

The relevant part of the standard that deals with init-list constructors is *§13.3.1.7/1* **[over.match.list]** - citation below taken from a now-deleted answer of @Praetorian -

> When objects of non-aggregate class type *T* are list-initialized such that 8.5.4 specifies that overload resolution is performed according to the rules in this section, overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>   — **Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.**
>   — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements
>   of the initializer list.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the implicit conversions went that deep. Great thinking with the `explicit` keyword!

Comment: @LB-- tricky indeed, couldn't fall asleep thinking about it :) But I guess that's what's going on.

Comment: Nailed it (+1); if there's a way to torture your code into using an `initalizer_list` constructor, the compiler is required to do it. @Praetorian's now-deleted answer contains the relevant quotes.

Comment: @Praetorian I have added the standard citation from your deleted answer, hope it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no C++ expert but the main difference is that

```
test{a{}}
```

Does not have an overload for `initializer_list<a>` so that constructor is not available.

On the other hand `test{t{v}}` does have an `initializer_list<test>` constructor available to it because you can create a `test` from vector. It can use the (I don't know the name of the rule) 1 cast transformation.

```
test{t{v}} -> test{test(t{v})}
```

Comment: What causes the error to return in the second example when you substitute `b` with `test`? (By the way, I think you're really close with the second half of your answer, but this is confusing for me to think about)

Comment: @LB-- I guess that by using the curly-braces it prefers `initialization_list`s because that's what the language says? but we need a language lawyer to know this exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you're writing a function calling itself.

```
test(std::initializer_list<test> v)
    : test{t{v}} //error
    {
    }
```

`test{t{v}}` will first call the initializer-list of `vector<test>` with v as parameter. But `vector` will call the function again to initialize the value which will fail.

The compiler doesn't know how to resolve the problem. Changing the initialization to use parentheses will (as you said) fix this because it will then call an implicit copy constructor in the `vector` (doing nothing because the your structure isn't doing anything).

The second example starts with this call: `a{}`

It is resolved fine because `a` is a basic structure with implicitly defined constructors. The second call is the `test{...}` one

Because the type is `a` and there is a constructor for `a` it runs just fine.

Comment: What about the second example which compiles just fine?

Comment: The second example doesn't use the value you send it so it's not calling the same function: you send a `b` and you call the constructor with a `a` so there is no conflict.

Comment: In the first example, I send an initializer list of `test` but I call the ctor which takes a vector of `test` - they are completely disparate types.

Comment: I might be reading wrong but this `test{t{v}}` is 2 calls of initialiser-list nested. First you make a new `vector` out of the first one then you put it in an initialiser-list and give it to `test` again. What would work is calling explicitly the `test(t const &v)` (by using parentheses) instead of using brackets (calling the same function again).

Comment: How does a `vector<test>` fit into an `initializer_list<test>`? As shown by the second example, the compiler shouldn't even consider it as an option. The whole point of this question is to understand what makes the difference between `a` and `b` versus `vector<test>` and `initializer_list<test>`.

Comment: Sorry about that I misread your code (you could have picked better names). The second case has an initializer_list using a different type than itself. This is the main difference here.

Comment: Would you change your answer to properly explain this phenomenon? Explain why replacing `b` with `test` causes the error to reappear.

Comment: The `vector<test>` itself will call your function, not the `t{..}` part. Plus it doesn't make sense to write this instead of calling directly a copy constructor

Comment: Why is it a compile time error and not runtime infinite recursion, then?

Comment: @LB-- The compiler has enough static information to idenitfy the infinite loop. For initialization of `vector<test>` elements there is a call to exactly the same constructor

Comment: @icepack My point is that the problem is not caused by the actions of what `vector<test>` does internally - take the second example and replace `b` with `test`. We are only using `a`'s default constructor, but the error reappears anyway.